# Get Order Information and Customer Information on external site

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, http-redirect

I am developing a Magento site for SaaS(www.openerpengines.com).

I have placed a button on the Success page(the page which comes after placing order). When the User clicks on the button, I want to post or you can send the customer information and order information to an external site.

Can any one help me out. I am trying to achieve this stuff since 2 days.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could send a JSON request upon clicking the button to an endpoint on the external site. From there the external site can take the data and save/do with it as required.

Not sure if Magneto provides a good way of doing that, but in principle that's what I'd do in a custom app.

Comment: Cant i send this Information using a POST Method, by getting the required information in some html elements